# How can I prevent a form from being displayed in the privatemsg module?

Tags: forms, privatemsg

I am trying to remove the "Block a user" fieldset, username text and input field, and "Block user" button from the "Blocked users" page as shown below.

[image: Privatemsg screenshot]

The code I'm trying to change is in the pm_block_user module:

```
/**
 * Formbuilder function to build a simple form to block users.
 */
function pm_block_user_list() {
  global $user;
  $form['new'] = array(
    '#type'   => 'fieldset',
    '#title'  => t('Block a user'),
  );
  $form['new']['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Username'),
    '#autocomplete_path' => 'messages/user/autocomplete',
    '#description'        => t('Separate multiple names with commas.'),
    '#required'          => TRUE,
  );
  $form['new']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Block user'),
    '#validate' => array('pm_block_user_block_validate'),
    '#submit' => array('pm_block_user_block_submit'),
  );

  $header = array(
    array(
      'data' => t('Username'),
      'field' => 'u.name',
      'sort'  => 'asc',
      ),
    array(
      'data' => t('Operations'),
      ),
  );

  $select = db_select('pm_block_user', 'pmb')->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort')
    ->fields('pmb', array('author'))
    ->condition('pmb.recipient', $user->uid)
    ->limit(20)
    ->orderByHeader($header);

  // Only show existing users, therefore join users.
  $select->innerJoin('users', 'u', 'u.uid = pmb.author');

  $rows = array();
  foreach ($select->execute() as $row) {
    $rows[] = array(
      theme('username', array('account' => user_load($row->author))),
      l(t('unblock'), 'messages/block/' . $row->author, array('query' => drupal_get_destination())),
    );
  }
  $form['#header'] = $header;
  $form['#rows'] = $rows;
  return $form;
}
```

Here is the code I tried in my template.php based on [these instructions for removing unwanted elements from forms](http://drupal.org/node/368776):

```
function MYMODULE_pm_block_user_list($form) {
  unset($form['new']['#title']);
  unset($form['new']['#type']);
  return drupal_render($form);
}
```

However, this code hides the "Username/Tom/Operations/unblock" section, not the "Block a user" section which I am trying to hide.

Comment: may be hook_form_alter help you by removing form elements and render empty form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does it for me:

```
function MYMODULE_form_pm_block_user_list_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  unset($form['new']);
}
```

This should help if you didn't know about it.

[`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter();`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

Also there's the more generic [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

Comment: as I said in my comment ;)

Comment: meh...maybe it should have been an answer.  That way you could have posted an example and maybe some documentation links.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll add the documentation links to my bookmarks.